# Newer OpenGL version through software rendering?

Tags: debian, opengl

Suppose I want to run an application requiring OpenGL 4.5 but my hardware only supports OpenGL 3.3.

**Performance issues aside,** is there some sort of software renderer available that provides 4.5 capabilities?

I'm aware that you can `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1`, but that only seems to make 1.4 available.